# How to convert php code below to Code Igniter code?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$exp_time = time() - (3600 * $set['jam_pembayaran']);
$q=$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM transaksi WHERE (tr_pembayaran ='bank_bca' OR tr_pembayaran ='bank_mandiri' OR tr_pembayaran ='bank_bni' OR tr_pembayaran ='bank_bri') AND (tr_status_pembayaran='pending') AND (tr_tanggal > '$exp_time')");
if ($q->rowCount()){
foreach($q->fetchAll() as $trx){
@file_get_contents(site_url('/payment/'.$trx->tr_pembayaran.'/id/'.$trx->tr_id));}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following query in `codeigniter`.You have to use query grouping for proper output.

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')->from('transaksi')
        ->group_start()
                ->where('tr_pembayaran', 'bank_bca')
                ->or_where('tr_pembayaran','bank_mandiri')
                ->or_where('tr_pembayaran','bank_bni')
                ->or_where('tr_pembayaran','bank_bri')
        ->group_end()        
        ->where('tr_status_pembayaran', 'pending')
        ->where('tr_tanggal >', $exp_time)
      ->get();
if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
  $res = $query->result();
foreach($res as $trx){
@file_get_contents(site_url('/payment/'.$trx->tr_pembayaran.'/id/'.$trx->tr_id));
}
}
```

For more see here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

Comment: anyone can teach me how to create views and controller function?

Comment: I think you are going to start learning codeigniter.see here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Answer (score 0):

Codeignitor code.
In your model write an function

```
$exp_time = time() - (3600 * $set['jam_pembayaran']);
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('transaksi');
$this->db->where('tr_pembayaran' ,'bank_bca');
$this->db->or_where('tr_pembayaran' ,'bank_mandiri');
$this->db->or_where('tr_pembayaran' ,'bank_bni');
$this->db->or_where('tr_pembayaran' ,'bank_bri');
$this->db->where('(tr_status_pembayaran' ,'pending');
$this->db->where('tr_tanggal > ','$exp_time)');
$query = $this->db->get(); 

if ($query->num_rows()){
foreach($query->result() as $r){
@file_get_contents(site_url('/payment/'.$r->tr_pembayaran.'/id/'.$r-    >tr_id));}}
```